# IP header length and version field

Tags: networking, network-programming, ip, system-verilog, tcp

I was recently trying to create a TCP/IP packet generator and checker in System Verilog. To validate my code I was comparing the generator output with the IP Golden output.

I was able to match almost all the fields with the Golden output but the IP header and version fields seemed to differ. I had generated the packet with IP version being 4 and IHL as 5.

Here is a summary of the bit fields of the internet header:

```
 0                   1                   2                   3   
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|Version|  IHL  |Type of Service|          Total Length         |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

As per the above mentioned bit fields position, we have bits 0:3 as Version and bits 4:7 as IHL. Now, the byte transmitted is formed by concatenating the two fields. So, in the generator code I had the Version as the LSB part of the byte and IHL in the MSB part of the byte. As a result the byte formed is 0x54 but in the Golden output I see that the byte is actually 0x45 which looks reversed?

Here are the two outputs:

Generator output:

```
0000   00 a0 12 01 01 01 00 a0 12 01 01 02 08 00 **54** 00
0010   00 38 30 39 40 00 80 06 5a c9 0a 2a 5a a9 0a 00
0020   00 eb 00 0b 00 37 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 50 08
0030   00 03 03 87 04 00 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09
0040   0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f
```

Golden output:

```
0000   00 a0 12 01 01 01 00 a0 12 01 01 02 08 00 **45** 00
0010   00 38 30 39 40 00 80 06 5a c9 0a 2a 5a a9 0a 00
0020   00 eb 00 0b 00 37 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 50 08
0030   00 03 03 87 04 00 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09
0040   0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f
```

Not sure if I am missing something here? Please suggest.

Thank you.

Comment: You must use the correct order. The Version field will be the first four bits (highest order) of the IP header. I'm not sure why you are trying to make it the lowest order nibble of the first byte. You need to use Network Byte Order and Network Bit Order. This can be a problem with Intel (Little-Endian) processors because it should be Big-Endian. "_**3.2. Network Bit Order** For certain low-level protocols or compression-oriented media types, bit-order may be an issue.  When possible, big-endian is encouraged for consistancy with Network Byte Order._"

Comment: I was aware about the Network byte order but not aware of the Network Bit Order. It is because of the Network Bit order we are assuming the first bit as the most significant one (this means that we're assuming big-endian bit order within the byte) something I didn't knew earlier. 
Thank you Ron for pointing me to "Network Bit Order" concept.

Comment: @RonMaupin If we are using the Network bit order for the version and IHL field, then shouldn't we use for every other field of the packet as well? Will that be the case?

Comment: Also, why don't we use the htons function on the 16-bits formed by using DSCP, IHL and Version? Since the first byte transferred is the byte formed by combining IHL and version field which suggests that we haven't actually converted it to network order (big-Endian)

Comment: Simply transferring the bits in the order from `0` to `31` is Network Byte Order (big-endian), which is how you are supposed to transmit them. I will post a more complete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When referring to the bit and byte order represented by IETF protocols, e.g. IPv4, you use Network Byte Order (big-endian). In your example, the bits are transmitted in the order which they are numbered: `0` to `31`, and this results in Network Byte Order. As a result, you will transmit the Version before you transmit the IHL, which is the opposite of what you are trying to do, and it results in the first byte transmitted as `0x45`

This is explained in [*RFC 1700, ASSIGNED NUMBERS*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1700):

> Data Notations
>
> The convention in the documentation of Internet Protocols is to
> express numbers in decimal and to picture data in "big-endian" order
> [[COHEN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1700#ref-COHEN)].  That is, fields are described left to right, with the
> most significant octet on the left and the least significant octet on
> the right.
>
> The order of transmission of the header and data described in this
> document is resolved to the octet level.  Whenever a diagram shows a
> group of octets, the order of transmission of those octets is the
> normal order in which they are read in English.  For example, in the
> following diagram the octets are transmitted in the order they are
> numbered.
>
> ```
>  0                   1                   2                   3
>  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |       1       |       2       |       3       |       4       |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |       5       |       6       |       7       |       8       |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |       9       |      10       |      11       |      12       |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> ```
>
> Transmission Order of Bytes
>
> Whenever an octet represents a numeric quantity the left most bit in
> the diagram is the high order or most significant bit.  That is, the
> bit labeled 0 is the most significant bit.  For example, the following
> diagram represents the value 170 (decimal).
>
> ```
>                       0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
>                      +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>                      |1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0|
>                      +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> ```
>
> Significance of Bits
>
> Similarly, whenever a multi-octet field represents a numeric quantity
> the left most bit of the whole field is the most significant bit.
> When a multi-octet quantity is transmitted the most significant octet
> is transmitted first.